# No such customer error in Stripe when trying to create a Customer object

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to build a subscription service based web app where users get charged monthly for using my web app. I'm using PHP for said app, with the Stripe library installed via Composer. I've created a handy `process_payment` function to process payments for my registered users:

```
/**
 * process_payment
 * Process a payment using Stripe
 * @param  User $user
 * @param  int $amount - amount in cents
 * @param  string $payment_method - optional payment method ID
 * @return bool - true if successful, false if not
 */
function process_payment($user, $amount, $payment_method = '')
{
    loadEnv();
    //! TODO: Change this to live mode when deploying
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($_ENV['STRIPE_TEST_SKEY']);

    try
    {
        if ($payment_method != '') // First time charge
        {
            $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                'amount' => $amount,
                'currency' => CURRENCY_CODE,
                'payment_method' => $payment_method,
                'customer' => $user->id,
                'off_session' => true,
                'confirm' => true,
            ]);         
        } 
        
        else // Renewal Charge
        {
            $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                'amount' => $amount,
                'currency' => CURRENCY_CODE,
                'customer' => $user->id,
                'off_session' => true,
                'confirm' => true,
            ]);
        }

        return true;
    } 

    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $errorMessage = 'Stripe Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        file_put_contents('error.log', date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . $errorMessage . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I just can't seem to make this work. I need help creating a Customer object to store within Stripe when there's a first time payment (`$payment_method` variable is set, passed from Stripe.js widget). When I try a first time charge, I get the following Stripe API exception: `No such customer: '81c762ec-3b11-4d76-b799-f4da6a105c98'`

I was expecting it to create a new Customer object, then confirm the charge.

Comment: `customer` here refers to Stripe Customer ID (cus_xxx) created from [Customer Creation API](https://docs.stripe.com/api/customers/create), not your own internal customer ID. You should create a Stripe Customer first, then use it in Payment Intent.